# Best way to convert a PriorityQueue to a sorted array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, java-stream, priority-queue

I am concerned with different styles of creating a sorted array from a Java PriorityQueue containing a few thousand elements. The [Java 8 docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) say

> If you need ordered traversal, consider using Arrays.sort(pq.toArray()).

However, I do like the streaming API, so what I had at first was

```
Something[] elems = theHeap.stream().sorted(BY_CRITERION.reversed())
                       .toArray(Something[]::new);
```

(Where `BY_CRITERION` is the custom comparator of the PriorityQueue, and I do want the reverse order of that.) Is there any disadvantage to using this idiom, as compared to the following:

```
Something[] elems = theHeap.toArray(new Something[0]);
Arrays.sort(elems, BY_CRITERION.reversed());
```

This latter code certainly appears to be following the API doc recommendation more directly, but apart from that, is it really more efficient in terms of memory, such as fewer temporary structures being allocated etc.?

I would think that the streaming solution would have to buffer the stream elements in a temporary structure (an array?) and then sort them, and finally copy the sorted elements to the array allocated in `toArray()`.

While the imperative solution would buffer the heap elements in a newly allocated array and then sort them. So this might be one copy operation fewer. (And one array allocation. The discussion of  `Collection.toArray(new T[size])` vs. `Collection.toArray(new T[0])` is tangentially related here. For example, see [here](https://shipilev.net/blog/2016/arrays-wisdom-ancients/#_conclusion) for why on OpenJDK the latter is faster.)

And what about sorting efficiency? The docs of [Arrays.sort()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-T:A-java.util.Comparator-) say

> Temporary storage requirements vary from a small constant for nearly sorted input arrays to n/2 object references for randomly ordered input arrays

while the documentation of `Stream.sorted()` is silent on this point. So at least in terms of being reliably documented, the imperative solution would seem to have an advantage.

But is there anything more to know?

Comment: Not using streams is almost always the more performant choice (unless you use `.parallel()` and hava data in the size of millions of entries)

Comment: why sorting again if priority queue is already giving you the elements in sorted order.

Comment: initialize priorityQueue with `BY_CRITERION.reversed()` as a comparator

Comment: @SleimanJneidi Because it isn't. Only peek() and poll() respect the comparator. There is no method for ordered traversal. This is specified in the documentation.

Comment: @Lino I actually need the smallest queue element to be determined one way and still sometimes traverse the queue another way. But that's really besides the point. Anyway, the general caveat that "usually small serial streams are slow" is well-placed. But still, what is it that makes them slower than the array-based approach?

Comment: @Sebastian the point about streams is that they express *what* they do, but not *how* they do it. Internally they use a lot of objects, create new references here and there. It looks nice. But performance wise it is as said for serial at least not the best option. Whereas with the array approach just one array is created and then it is sorted. No more action is done on it. That's why it is faster

Comment: So you want to have a PQ *and* a sorted array? That's a rather odd requirement. If you have a sorted array, then there's no need to have a PQ representation of the same data, unless you'll be adding more elements. And if you continually need access to the max and the min items, then you probably want something like a [min-max heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_heap)

Comment: @JimMischel Let's not go into the detailed requirements of my use case. That is really beside the point of my question. Suffice it to say that I need the sorted array exactly once, namely when finally showing a list of surviving elements to a user, in wich case it may need to be sorted by something different than the queue priority (e. g. top-down as in my example, or lexicographically by ID, whatever).

Comment: Then do it in whatever way makes sense. You're talking "a few thousand" elements, so even O(n) extra space isn't going to make much difference. Write it however you like. If it works and doesn't cause problems, which is highly likely, then you're done. Your worries about efficiency and excess memory usage are premature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fundamentally, both variants do the same and since both are valid solutions within the library’s intended use cases, there is no reason why the implementations should prefer one over the other regarding choosing algorithms or adding optimizations.

In practice, this means that the most expensive operation, the sorting, ends up at the same implementation methods internally. The `sorted(…)` operation of the Stream implementation buffers all elements into an intermediate array, followed by calling `Arrays.sort(T[], int, int, Comparator<? super T>)`, which will delegate to the same method as the method `Arrays.sort(T[], Comparator<? super T>)` you use in your first variant, the target being a sort method within the internal `TimSort` class.

So everything that has been said about the time and space complexity for `Arrays.sort` applies to the `Stream.sort` as well. But there is a performance difference though. For the OpenJDK implementations up to Java 10, the Stream is not capable of fusing the `sorted` with the subsequent `toArray` step, to directly use the result array for the sorting step. So currently, the Stream variant bears a final copying step from the intermediate array used for sorting to the final array created by the function passed to `toArray`. But future implementations might learn this trick, then, there will be no relevant performance different at all between the two solutions.